# Connection problems on Netgear DG834v4 ADSL modem

Tags: modem, adsl

I can't get a connection on this device using my client's ISP login, nor my ADSL login I use at home.  It is syncing nicely and I have a solid DSL light, but a red Internet light for either login.  I suspect something more than just the login is faulty.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your client's ISP. Try a different modem if you can, otherwise I think I would just give them a call.

Comment: Has the problem just started? Is this a new/recently statrted internet service?

Comment: No, it only started since I reset the modem to factory defaults - by accident, I meant to reset the wireless router :-( However, the line was terrible from Thursday until this morning, so it's hard to say.

Comment: I tried my ISP as well, same symptoms.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you tried your ADSL login over his modem, which also did not work, despite it working from your house. There could still be some fault with the connection between his house and his local exchange, or some other fault on the ISP's end of things. (Despite the DSL synching). Regardless, it's their job to fix it, and they should be able to diagnose it easier than we can I think.

Comment: Wow, same thing happened to me on TekSavvy with the same modem. Could it be that these things go bad after a year?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've since found out that the ADSL Setting: Multiplexing Mode was incorrectly set to "VC-BASED" (default), when "LLC-BASED" was the required setting.  Changing that and rebooting the modem worked fine.

Comment: Nope - mine is set to LLC and still doesn't want to connect... grrr

Answer (score 1):

I've used Netgear for awhile and though this seems to be an easy answer I found that no one even mentioned it.

When you install your Netgear adapter there are drivers that will override your system app for identifying open networks. In my experience I installed the drivers first – i.e. seperately – then installed the adapter and the new drivers picked up the adapter (it being one of their own) and had no problem with connection.

They seem to fight for the default position, and the only problem I had was in keeping the connection on for a while. Then, restarting the computer, I found I had to reinstall drivers again to get that fresh connection.

I also found that Netgear adapters work better if they are kept cool (maybe it's just me) — let's face it: they are thrown together cheaply. I wound up changing to Belkin myself.